# Dúvida sobre erro 404 inexistente

Tags: php, framework, zend

Estou com uma dúvida, e não sei o que fazer. Estou utilizando o Zend Framework 1.12, PHP5.6. Ocorre que meu sistema está em um subdiretório chamado "sistema":

/sistema/application/...

Minha pasta pública:

/sistema/public/

Em algumas requisições dos sistema, como por exemplo uma view que é renderizada com o angularjs, que está dentro da pasta /sistema/public/pangularjs/html/template.html, outro exemplo são arquivos php que estão diretamente na raiz da pasta /sistema/public/sub/arquivos.php, são acessado diretamente na URL, porém toda vez que eu chamo um destes arquivos públicos, o framework tenta encontrar esta pasta como se ele fosse um método do sistema, então ele tenta carregar como "sistemaAction" e entra na exceção de erro 404, como o arquivo existe na pasta pública ele pula a exceção do erro 404 e carrega o arquivo. Mas grava o log de erro 404. Como eu poderia fazer para evitar ou ignorar essa verificação toda vez que chamo um arquivo da pasta pública, pois não tem necessidade de verificar exceções em arquivos que existem.